# How do I get all members with a role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to send a DM to all members with a specific role. I've tried that to get members with a role:

```
guild.roles.cache.get(ROLE_ID).members
```

and

```
guild.roles.fetch(ROLE_ID)
```

My problem is that the bot only returns my user.

I know someone has asked a question like this before where it was solved using the correct `intents`, but it's not the case for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that [`Role#members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members) returns a Collection of the **cached** guild members only that have this role. Try to fetch all members first and then try again:

```js
let members = await guild.members.fetch()
let membersWithRole = guild.roles.cache.get(ROLE_ID).members
```

Or you can just [`filter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) the `members` by their role:

```js
let members = await guild.members.fetch()
let membersWithRole = members.filter(member => member.roles.cache.has(ROLE_ID));
```